# Play Framework: Redirect to controller method with arguments

Tags: java, playframework, http-get, playframework-2.2

I am building a web application with PLAY framework 2.2.1 and am trying to display all available http get query parameters for the requested site in the address bar, even the ones that are not set in the request. In cases where
not all http get parameters are set, I want to add the unset parameters with the default values and make a redirect.

I have a site that can be requested with GET:

```
GET /test controllers.Application.test(q:String, w:String ?= null, f:String ?= null, o:String ?= null)
```

Here is the method that I'd like to have in `controllers.Application`:

```
public static Result test(String q, String w, String f, String o){

    ...

    // In case not all parameters where set
    if (reload == 1){
            return redirect(controllers.Application.test(qDefault, wDefault, fDefault, oDefault));
    }
    else {
        ok(...);
    }
}
```

The problem is that redirect() takes a String and not a Result object.

My first solution is to write

```
return controllers.Application.test(qDefault, wDefault, fDefault, oDefault);
```

But unfortunately the adress bar does not update.

My second solution is to build the string manually:

```
return redirect("/test?q=" + query + "&f=" + f + "&w=" + w + "&o=" + showOptions);
```

This works fine, but is there no other way more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `routes` object :

```
public static Result index() {
    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.test(qDefault, wDefault, fDefault, oDefault)); 
}
```

Source : [Official Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaRouting)

Answer (score 2):

in addition this is also valid

```
public static Result index() {
    return redirect("path"); 
}
```