# Play Framework: Redirect to controller method with string argument doesn't work

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to redirect to a controller method which is taking Long and String as argument by using the reverse controller. I use version 2.4 of the play framework.

I've defined this route in the routes file:

```
GET     /games/play/:id    controllers.Games.renderGame(id: Long, feedback: String = "")
```

To call this route, I'm using in a other method redirect():

```
return redirect(controllers.routes.Games.renderGame(gameId, "test"));
```

And here is my renderGame() method:

```
public Result renderGame(Long id, String feedback) {
   //do something
   return ok(...);
}
```

In my opinion this actually should work but play gives me a error:

> error: method renderGame in class ReverseGames cannot be applied to
>   given types;

IntelliJ is trying to do it better:
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcwzY.png)

If I define the method just with Long as parameter it's working fine but when a add the String I get the error again.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Related to this Question, it actually should work: [Play Framework: Redirect to controller method with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233156/play-framework-redirect-to-controller-method-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself but it tooks me hours. The problem was that I used a `=` instead of `=?`. It has to look like this:

```
GET     /games/play/:id                 controllers.Games.renderGame(id: Long, feedback: String ?= "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the route definition try adding `feedback` params at the url pattern

```
GET     /games/play/:id/:feedback    controllers.Games.renderGame(id: Long, feedback: String = "")
```

cheers.

Comment: But shouldn't it work related to this post: [Play Framework: Redirect to controller method with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233156/play-framework-redirect-to-controller-method-with-arguments).

And unfortunally I got an error: It is not allowed to specify a fixed or default value for parameter: 'feedback' extracted from the path